# Table Column Width Error

Tags: tables, width

I'm trying to produce a table in LaTeX and I almost succeed.
The table is this one:

[image: LaTeX Table]

My question is: why the fourth column of "Gennaio", "Febbraio" and "Maggio" isn't as the same width as the rest? What do I need to modify in the code to overcome this problem?

The code is the following one:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{cllllllllllllllllllll}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                              & \multicolumn{4}{c}{GENNAIO}                                                                                                                                                                   & \multicolumn{4}{c}{FEBBRAIO}                                                                                                                                                                  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{MARZO}                                                                                                                                                                     & \multicolumn{4}{c}{APRILE}                                                                                                                                                                    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{MAGGIO}                                                                                                                                                                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Collezione\\ Dati\end{tabular}}   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{}                                                                                                                                                                         & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{}                                                                                                                                                                      \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Elaborazione\\ Dati\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{}                                                                                                                                                                         & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{}                                                                                                                                                                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}} & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{}                                                                                                                                                                        \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Report\\ Dati\end{tabular}}       & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{}                                                                                                                                                                         & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{}                                                                                                                                                                         & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{}                                                                                                                                                                         & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{}                                                                                                                                                                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Thanks to anyone who has the patience to help me!
R.

Comment: in the underlying `\halign` primitive, if a spanning cell is wider than the cells it spans all the width goes in the last spanned column

Comment: change you `llllll` to `*{16}{p{10mm}}` or whatever size works to force your columns equal width with 4 of them being just wider than your header text

Comment: Please put full MWE, with preamble containing all called packages. Guessing them speeds down thinking on your problem.

Comment: Thank you David for helping!
I tried your solutions, then I put:

Comment: @DavidCarlisle
Thank you David for helping!
I tried your solution, then I inserted the following lines:
`\usepackage{array, multirow}`
`\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3em}}`
`\begin{tabular}{*{21}{|C}|}`

But the table width doesn't change. Maybe I just didn't understand your answer!

@PrzemysławScherwentke
Thank you for answering!
For this table I'm using the following packages:
`\usepackage{graphicx, array, booktabs, multirow}`
and I added this line in the preamble:
`\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3em}}`

Comment: `3em` probably isn't enough, try 30 and decrease (If you'd supplied a test example I would probably have tested to get the right value myself)

Comment: Dear David, I'm trying 30em, 20em, 10em, 0.5em even 80em, but the table doesn't change! It's always the same. Sorry, I didn't understand what do you mean with "test example", can you please explain me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  the `tabularx` package. Here is a code, also using the `makecell` package, in order to have a common formatting of column and row heads, and the possibility of linebreaks inside cells:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[nomarginpar, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[HTML]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, tabularx, makecell, colortbl}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadset{\setstretch{1.333}}
\newcommand\multicolthead[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{\thead{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|*{20}{>{\arraybackslash}X|}}
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{}& \multicolthead{4}{GENNAIO}& \multicolthead{4}{FEBBRAIO} & \multicolthead{4}{MARZO} & \multicolthead{4}{APRILE} & \multicolthead{4}{MAGGIO} \\
\hline
\thead{Collezione\\ Dati} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}& \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} &\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & & & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{} \\
\hline
\thead{Elaborazione\\ Dati} & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{} & & & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\thead{Report\\ Dati} & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. Wonderful.
I should learn `tabularx`, it seems more powerful than `tabular`.
Bernard, you gave me the solution and I have a question related to your code, if I can: what does it produce this code `{>{\arraybackslash}X|}}`
Thank you again,
R.

Comment: `\arraybackslash` is really needed only in the last column. It says to latex to interpret `\\` as meaning `tabularnewline` (in X columns, there can be linebreaks inside cells).

Comment: I didn't understand, but I think I'm too ignorant.
Again, thank you very much Bernard for the help!

Comment: @user51937: Some cells are `\parbox`es, hence you can use `\\` inside them. However, in tables, `\\` also means really: ‘what follows is a new row’,, so that it can be confusing for latex in some situations, and you can have error messages on compiling. `\arraybackslash` disambiguates the situation and avoids error messages — at least in most cases.

Comment: Dear @Bernard, sorry if I come back in this thread, but I have a question that for you will be a lot easier than it would be for me: how can I reduce the size of the boxes in that table? I mean reduce the space between "Collezione" and the upper line, "Elaborazione" and the upper line and "Report" and the upper line.
Thank you!
R.

Comment: @user51937: You're welcome. It's due to the `\renewcommand\arraystretch{3}` command. It seemed to correspond to the aspect ratio of the rectangles in your question. I removed it from the code, and replaced it with a change in `\baselinestretch` *inside*  column heads. Is it OK now?

Comment: Dear @Bernard, I removed `\renewcommand\arraystretch{3}` from the code and added `\renewcommand\theadset{\setstretch{1.333}}` in the preamble. Then I left everything unchanged, as in your code. When I tried to compile, LaTeX produces an error: 

`! Undefined control sequence.`
`\theadset ->\setstretch`
`{1.333}`
`l.145 \end{tabularx}`
`The control sequence at the end of the top line`
`of your error message was never \def'ed.`

I tried to modify the `1.333` but the error it's still there.

Comment: @user51937: Sorry! I forgot to mention adding `\usepackage{setspace}`.

Comment: Oh yeah! That's rule man!
Before I used this `\renewcommand\theadset{\setstretch{}}` and it worked! Even if compiling gives an error, the pdf document was correctly produced :)
Anyway, thank you again @Bernard for your BIG support!
Have a nice day and tell me if you come in Italy, I will give you my support!

Answer (score 0):

I come back in this thread to ask something really related.

I need to compile the following code, representing a table, quite similar the one you made. But something doesn't work with the last column, I think.

```
\begin{table}[h!]
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|*{20}{>{\arraybackslash}X|}}

\multicolumn{1}{c}{}& \multicolthead{3}{\color{RoyalBlue}\textbf{I}}& \multicolthead{3}{\color{RoyalBlue}\textbf{II}} & \multicolthead{3}{\color{RoyalBlue}\textbf{III}} & \multicolthead{3}{\color{RoyalBlue}\textbf{IV}} & \multicolthead{3}{\color{RoyalBlue}\textbf{V}} & \multicolthead{3}{\color{RoyalBlue}\textbf{VI}} \\

\hline

\thead{\color{RoyalBlue}One\\\color{RoyalBlue} Time} & \cellcolor[HTML]{D3D3D3} & \cellcolor[HTML]{D3D3D3} & & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} \\

\hline

\thead{\color{RoyalBlue}Two\\\color{RoyalBlue} Times} & & & \cellcolor[HTML]{D3D3D3} & \cellcolor[HTML]{D3D3D3} & & & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} & \\

\hline

\thead{\color{RoyalBlue}Three\\\color{RoyalBlue}Times} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} & & \cellcolor[HTML]{D3D3D3} & \cellcolor[HTML]{D3D3D3} & \cellcolor[HTML]{D3D3D3} & \cellcolor[HTML]{D3D3D3} & \cellcolor[HTML]{D3D3D3} & \cellcolor[HTML]{D3D3D3} & \cellcolor[HTML]{D3D3D3} & \cellcolor[HTML]{D3D3D3} & \cellcolor[HTML]{D3D3D3} & & & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} \\ 

\hline

\thead{\color{RoyalBlue}Four\\\color{RoyalBlue} \& Times} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} & & \cellcolor[HTML]{D3D3D3} & \cellcolor[HTML]{D3D3D3} & \cellcolor[HTML]{D3D3D3} & & \\

\hline

\end{tabularx}
 \end{table}
```

Which gives the following output:

[image: Table Wrong Last Column]

Thanks for help!
R.